# How to compile OpenCv project and cmake

Tags: opencv, cmake, opencv3.0

I am working on Windows and I have already compiled opencv 3.2  in cmake on MS Visual Studio 2010. Now I want to make a test a create small project example.
But I don"t know how should look like CMakeLists.
I want to compile OpenCv example code in *.cpp file with cmake.

Could anyone help me please ?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) 

PROJECT (TestOpenCV)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_executable(test1 test1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test1 OpenCV ${OpenCV_LIBS})

link_directories(${OpenCV_LIB_DIR})
```

?????

because after I got a link error concerning OpenCV.lib ?

I would appreciate for any help please.

Comment: `I got a link error concerning OpenCV.lib` - In `target_link_libraries()` you list *plain* `OpenCV`, that is why linker tries to find it. Remove that argument: **all** OpenCV libraries are already listed in variable *OpenCV_LIBS*.

Comment: Your question is kind of not clear what do you mean by opencv compile do you want to build opencv from source using cmake or you want to compile opencv project using any language?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help :)
Issue fixed. Now it is working fine with MS Visual Studio 2010 and CMake 2.8.11

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) 

PROJECT (TestOpenCV)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_executable(test1 test1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test1 ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```